# Почему function неправлиьно работает?

Tags: jquery

Добрый вечер, подскажите почему функция отрабатывает неправильно, в теле я создал контейнер для кастомного скрола, ниже на js подключаются скролбары, по условию певрая функция должна аттачить скролл на определенный класс если ширина выше 666 пикселей, иначе уничтожать, вторая функция для другого контейнера уничтожает скрол если ширина меньше 424 пискслеей а иначе добалвяет скрол, я не совсем пойму почему на данный момент отрабатывает первая функция когда для не создан контейнер, но она отрабатывает на контейнре второй функции, те скролл каког-то фига атачится если ширина контейнера больше 666 пикселей, хотя в условии нет такой проверки, если удалить первую функцию тогда работает как должно.

```
`   https://jsfiddle.net/4fqh2oy5/9/   `  Линк на фидл
```

[Линк на плагин](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/)

Comment: `$('.dash__content__tabs__scroll')` - здесь выбраны **все** элементы с данным классом

Comment: ))) там всего один(елемент), ниже вторая функция там другие классы, и если я инициализирую дестрой он уничтожит все, хотя я применяю destroy к определенному классу

Comment: например вот это $('.dash__content__tabs__scroll').mCustomScrollbar("destroy") уничтожит данный класс и другие классы с другой функции $('.menu__scroll, .dialog__scroll') Бред какой-то

Comment: почему ты так думаешь? Можешь сделать пример который можно запустить и посмотреть? Пока все выглядит нормально. В коде плагина в функции destroy обращение идет только к текущему селектору

Comment: @Grundy вот пример https://jsfiddle.net/gLvkz97r/33/

Comment: @Grundy  дичь какая-то, я специально вырезал один контейнер в котором должен быть второй скролл, так как скролы на разных страницах, и получается что первая функция  отрабатывает а вторая нет, хотя контейнера для первой функции вообще нет, а если убрать первую функцию тогда будет отарабатывать втоорая как нужно, открой инспектор и глянь, когда рисайзишь окно фидла атачатся классы дестрой к контейнеру, и получается что если контейнер меньше чем 424 пикселя должен происходить дистрой но он не происходит дистрой отрабатвает с landingScroll() на разришении 666 хотя там вообще нет этого контейнера

Comment: Это забавно :-) В двух словах: первый раз срабатывает верная инициализация из _menuScroll_, при этом к элементу menu__scroll добавляется класс скроллера. Далее в _landingScroll_ - он не находит ни одного элемента удовлетворяющего селектору, и берет дефолтный селектор, который совпадает с классом скроллера, в итоге он получает уже готовый скроллер и удаляет его :)